# webkit-transform on overflow:auto div results in vanishing scrollbar in Chrome

Tags: jquery, webkit

I've got an image loaded into an overflow:auto div.  On load, when you scroll the div, the scrollbar vanishes instantly.  I can get it to come back if I run, say, animate on the div's height (without even changing the height), but only *after* it's vanished.  After the animate, it's fixed for good.

I can fix this if I remove the -webkit-transform:translationZ(0); from the div's CSS, but I *need* the performance boost this provides (not for this little test program, but for the code it's derived from), so I can't remove it.

Any idea what's going on here, and how I might be able to fix it?

It's all in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/dB38c/5/

And also below:

HTML:

```
<div id="overflow"></div>
<p id="btn">click to fix</p>
```

CSS:

```
#overflow {
    overflow:auto;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    /* comment out the webkit-transform and the problem dissapears 
     * (but I need the transform for acceleration
     */
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var scrollbarWidth = 15;
var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+1);
//adding r to simulate non-cached images
var pagelink = 'http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1920-1920-4.jpg?'+r;

$('#overflow').html(
    "<img width='485' id='imgload' src='"+pagelink+"' />"
);

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#overflow').animate({height:200},0);
});
```

UPDATE: bug report filed: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129186

Comment: This is definately a bug in Chrome or WebKit and should be reported. I got it working by using `translateY(1)` but I'm not sure if that's even valid :)

Comment: by replacing my translateZ(0) with translateY(1)?  when I do that the bug goes away but so does the acceleration.

Comment: What about using `translateX(0)` then?

Comment: exact same behavior.  bug goes away, but so does acceleration.

Comment: interesting. Well I guess the bug appears as soon as hardware acceleration is enabled and seems there's no workaround atm.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome Stable and Canary (but not in Webkit Nightly). Can you report this to new.crbug.com ? The testcase is great, by the way.  In the meantime, you can apply `overflow:scroll` conditional on your own calculated size of the internals of the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a Chrome bug. I can reproduce this in Chrome Stable and Canary (but not in Webkit Nightly). Can you report this to new.crbug.com? The testcase is great, by the way.

### Workaround

In the meantime, you can apply `overflow:scroll` conditional on your own calculated size of the internals of the div.

In the case of your code,

```
var elem    = $('#overflow');
var heights = elem.children().map(function(){ return $(this).height(); }).get();
var sum     = _.reduce(heights], function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);

if (sum > elem.innerHeight()) elem.css('overflow', 'scroll');
```

I'm using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for the `reduce()` sugar, but you could do it without. Pretty sure there are some answers on SO for calculating sizes of child elements in order to do something like this (that are probably more robust than my approach).

Comment: will file the bug and will try out the workaround and report back.  thanks!

Comment: i must not be understanding how to integrate the workaround.  can you take a look and tell me what i'm missing?  http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/WCYr5/1/ .  also i believe you have an extra bracket before 'heights' in the var sum line.

Comment: i'm accepting this as an answer because it definitely answers my question (thx!). however, id still really appreciate clarification of the workaround if you have time.

Comment: It seems the bug is already reported as: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124532

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to the offending scrollable seems to fix the problem.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Check out the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dB38c/13/

Comment: i think google has fixed the bug so the old fiddle is already working in Chrome for me now.

Comment: The bug is only apparent when using a laptop with a touchpad and no mouse plugged in